# Retriving unique set of elements from different Sets

Tags: java

What method can be used to return a set of elements that can be found only in set a or set b,
but not in both Sets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

In theory, create a *union* of both sets and delete the *intersection*:

```
Set a = getSetA();
Set b = getSetB();

// create union
Set union = new Set(a);
union.addAll(b);

// remove intersection
for (Object inA : a)
  if(b.contains(inA))
    union.remove(inA);
```

Comment: You can create in intersection of two sets using `s1.retainAll(s2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<Integer>();

    s1.add(2); 
    s1.add(1);
    s2.add(3);
    s2.add(1);
```

[removeAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) :

> Removes from this set all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). If the specified collection is also a set, this operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the asymmetric set difference of the two sets.

```
    System.out.println(s2.removeAll(s1)); // true
    System.out.println(s2); // [3]
```

[retainAll (intersection)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) :

> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this set all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection. If the specified collection is also a set, this operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the intersection of the two sets

```
    System.out.println(s2.retainAll(s1)); // true
    System.out.println(s2);  // [1]
```

[addAll (union)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

> Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this set if they're not already present (optional operation).

```
    System.out.println(s1.addAll(s2)); //true
    System.out.println(s1);  //[1,2,3]
```

Comment: correct,So i need to delete the intersecting elements from union elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the difference. So for sets s1 and s2: s1.removeAll(s2)

Comment: No,actually I want to get all the different/uncommon elements  from 2 different sets - Set<Object> a, Set<Object> b.

Comment: Wouldn't that be only semi-correct? The objects in `s2` which are not in `s1` will not be in `s1` after the call. I didn't really understand the java doc for that one, though.

Comment: Ok then add the two differences to one set. Anyway I don't think there a standard method for this. You will have to write it yourself.